# convergence almost surely using SLLN

Tags: probability-theory

I'm working on the following problem from Resnick:

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d, $\mathbb{E}|X_1|<\infty$, $\mathbb{E}X_1=0$ and suppose that $\{c_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. Prove that 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i X_i \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0  \quad a.s.
$$
It's my first attempt:

*proof:* Let $Y_n:=c_nX_n1_{\{|X_n|\leq n\}}$ be the truncation of $X_n$. We observe 
\begin{align*}
 E|Y_n|&=E|c_nX_n1_{\{|X_n|\leq n\}}|=|c_n|E|X_n1_{\{|X_n|\leq n\}}| \\
&\leq KE|X_n1_{\{|X_n|\leq n\}}|  & |c_n|\leq K \\
&=K E|X_11_{\{|X_1|\leq 1\}}|& \textrm{i.i.d} \\
&<\infty &\textrm{assumption}
\end{align*}
Moreover, $E|Y_n|=E|Y_1|=0$ by i.i.d and assumption. Therefore by SLLN
we get the result i.e.

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i X_i \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0  \quad a.s.
$$

Comment: The proof is a bit  lengthy and you cannot directly apply Laws of Large Numbers. On p. 130 of Chung's 'A Course in Probability Theory' this is given as exercise 6) and there is a hint.

Comment: Yes, it says I should use truncation. I will check the proof again. Thanks.